# How to fix image size in header with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble setting my brand image in the header of my application. I tried using both `img-responsive` class and custom class `.brand` to set the height and width but the image either shrinks completely or just grows too big.

Am I missing any other div class or something else ?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/index.jsp">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/img/main-product-icon.png"/>
                Product Manager
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .img-responsive {
        max-width: 50px;  
        max-height: 20px; 
    }

    .brand {
        height: 100px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: cud u create a fiddle or code-runner here?

Comment: please you can create fiddle demo or codepen.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `max-height: 20px` in `img-responsive` and you're trying to set `height: 100px` in `brand`. You can increase the `max-height` property in `img-responsive` to a value greater than or equal to the `height` property in `brand`. Also, include both `img-responsive` and `brand` classes. I would also recommend removing the `max-width` property to keep the dimensions consistent.

Summary of the changes -

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/index.jsp">
   <img class="img-responsive brand" src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/img/main-product-icon.png"/>
   Product Manager
</a>

<style>
.img-responsive {
        //max-width: 50px;  
        max-height: 100px; 
    }

    .brand {
        height: 35px;
    }
</style>
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/o922npa7/1/) for a working fiddle with a sample logo.

EDIT - [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/o922npa7/3/) for a fiddle with the image and logo side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks Anish, I tried your solution in Fiddle, but my expectation was to keep the image and logo both in the same line, next to each other in the black bar.

Comment: @user2325154 I've updated the answer with a new fiddle to keep both the image and logo in the same line. Please accept my answer if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix the image size , you should give width and height to the image . because the img-responsive always take 100% width .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.brand {
        height: 100px !important;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.It works.

```
 <style>
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.img-responsive {
    max-width: 20px;  
    max-height: 20px; 
}

.abc 
{
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;

}
.xyz
{
     margin-top:0px;
     padding-top:5px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class = "adjust">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand xyz">
               <img class = "img-responsive abc" src="../../Images/chicago-school-college-exterior-renovation-photography.jpg" />
                Product Manager
            </a>

        </div></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```